# How to get a constructor name?

Tags: haskell

Consider I have:

```hs
data family P a
data instance P () = C1 (S.Set Int) | C2 -- and may be other constructors

let x = C1 (S.fromList mempty)
    y = C2
```

Is it a way to write a function which is able to get from `x` a `String` "C1" and from `y` - "C2"? Like:

```hs
cstrStringName :: ... -> String
cstrStringName = ...
```

Comment: This question sets off some alarm bells in my head. I strongly encourage you to find a Haskell expert to chat with and describe what you're trying to do and why you think that needs you to know a constructor's name as a `String`. It may be that there's a better or more idiomatic way to meet your needs, though you may need to take one or two steps back in your program design to find it.

Comment: @Iceland_jack The community has many mechanisms for chatting with experts. There is a very active IRC channel that is likely sufficient for something like this; or, for more substantive conversations, there are consultants available for hire. (And of course SO itself is a resource, if you can phrase your conversation in a way that doesn't require multiple rounds of communication.)

Comment: the idea was to create a newtype that add uniqueness to Set items based on their constructor, not on the default Ord, Eq instances that include the "content" (arguments) of the constructors as well. I done it already and it work as I expected. Another option is to use Map instead of but in this case key will be "unbound" (allows any permutations between keys/values) from the values that I don't like.